# getCenter is not a function jquery google map v3

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use jQuery to get the center value latlong using the below

**JQUERY**

```
$('.mapcentre').click(function(){   
    var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');
    var valMap = mapElement.getCenter();
    console.log(valMap);
});
```

my console.log outputs `TypeError: mapElement.getCenter is not a function` `var valMap = mapElement.getCenter();`

I'm unsure of what the problem is as the map I'm using shows up fine and this button `.mapcenter` when clicked should be getting the center lat and long of the area `#map`

Edit: the jQuery above is situated at he bottom of the active page.

EDIT again:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
        function init() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 2,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.697299 , -73.809815),
            };
            var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');
            var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
        }
```

Comment: you are calling getCenter() on javascript element.

Comment: @RameshK care to share how to fix this?

Comment: Actually your are calling getCenter on an HTML Element.  To help you fix this, we need to see your _map_ code.  The google.maps.Map has a getCenter method that returns the latitude and longitude coordinates of the center of the map.

Comment: @geocodezip have updated the original post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. put your map variable in the global scope:

   ```
   var map = null;
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
   function init() {
     var mapOptions = {
         zoom: 2,
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.697299 , -73.809815),
     };
     var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');
     map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
   }
   ```
2. call getCenter on it:

   ```
   $('.mapcentre').click(function(){   
     var valMap = map.getCenter();
     console.log(valMap);
   });
   ```

Answer (score -1):

just add this to your code...

```
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
  {
    size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
  });
```